# public.table name instead of table name only

Tags: postgresql

Everytime i delete a data it keeps saying that database name does not exist which it does.

Not sure why keeps asking me to put the 'public' + table name in my query instead just the table name .
e.g DELETE FROM tablename WHERE Name = 'Test'

Comment: It sounds like `public` is not in your search path. Check your search path:  `show search_path` or `select setting, source, boot_val, reset_val, sourcefile, sourceline
from pg_settings
where name = 'search_path';`

Comment: What exactly is the statement you are executing, and what exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: "database name does not exist " can not result in any message about a schema "public": When a database doesn't exist, you don get a database connection. And without a database connection you won't be able to execute any piece of SQL.